# Leak when converting CIImage to CGImage inside main queue

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I am creating a simple application in Xcode 7.1 iOS 9.1 (swift). The app takes a CMSampleBuffer from camera, converts it to CGImage and assigns it to UIImageView. When the app converts CIImage to CGImage inside the camera queue, the app works great. But when the app converts it inside the main queue, the app leaks.

Here is the leaked version:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    let buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
    let ciimg = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: buffer)
//  let cgimg = ViewController.cicontext.createCGImage(ciimg, fromRect: ciimg.extent)

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let cgimg = ViewController.cicontext.createCGImage(ciimg, fromRect: ciimg.extent)

        self.imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)
    })
}
```

If I comment "let cgimg" inside dispatch_sync and uncomment it above, the app does not leak. But for my app, I need to convert it inside the main queue.

It seems that the issue relates to reference counting inside dispatch_sync block.

Could anybody explain the leak?

Regards,
Valery.

Comment: You can declare cgimg outside like the commented code and can make a weak reference to use in dispatch_sync, I did like this in Obj-C but no idea about swift

Comment: If I uncomment, it is not important to use "weak". "let cgimg ..." outside sync works great without any leaks. But I need to call createCGImage inside sync. Or I missed something?

Comment: why you "must" call  createCGImage inside sync ???

Comment: I filed a bug to Apple. They fixed it in 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `cgimg` inside block then you should make it weak.

weak let cgimg = ViewController.cicontext.createCGImage(ciimg, fromRect: ciimg.extent)

Comment: I need to call createCGImage inside block. I removed all extra code to explain what problem I have.
I the app, I pass ciimg to my ViewController. It applies some CI filters and then creates CGImage using createCGImage. And I get leaks.

Comment: Do you mean:?
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            weak var cgimg = ViewController.cicontext.createCGImage(ciimg, fromRect: ciimg.extent)
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg!)
        })
This code crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can not reference strong object in `sync` operation. Try this;

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!,fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        let buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
        let ciimg = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: buffer)
        weak let cgimg = ViewController.cicontext.createCGImage(ciimg, fromRect: ciimg.extent)

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(CGImage: cgimg)
        })
    }
```

Comment: If I remove "weak" in your code, there will not be any leaks. The problem is that the app leaks if I call createCGImage inside block. And I must call it inside the block.